# How to query profiling collection in sharded cluster?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, aggregation-framework, database-administration

I have enable profiling with level 1 with 0 slowms parameter in my sharded cluster by enabling profiling on every every primary shard. When i fetch data of profiled collection it seems incomplete, like number of operations are higher but figure which i'm getting is low.

I have one doubt that it might getting data from only single shard and total i have 12 shards and result seem almost 1/12. As the system.profile collection don't have shard key or any unique id.

How to fetch data from profile collection to get data of all shard from router server.